# Is searching on android DDMS LOG possible?

Tags: android, logging, ddms

Any way to search within DDMS Log using some simple way more similar to (CTRL + F).
I know of filtering by LOG_TAG as well other simple way to copy-paste in a text document to do CTRL+F.

Comment: It seems its coming soon in ADT 14 as per this link http://tools.android.com/recent/updatedlogcatviewer
This certainly would be very useful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about **Eclipse** there isn't such search tool.

#### Here is my way to explore logs.

Rredircting `adb` shell output to the logfile.

```
adb logcat > device.log
```

Then explore logfile with vim. The only problem is that vim doesn't automatically reload file on change. So I adapted vim [filtering script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filter_buffer_on_a_search_result) to reload file on every search, just adding `edit!` line before search performing (line 8).

```js
" Gather search hits, and display in a new scratch buffer.
function! Gather(pattern)
  if !empty(a:pattern)
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let orig_ft = &ft
    " append search hits to results list
    let results = []
    edit!
    execute "g/" . a:pattern . "/call add(results, getline('.'))"
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    if !empty(results)
      " put list in new scratch buffer
      new
      setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
      execute "setlocal filetype=".orig_ft
      call append(1, results)
      1d  " delete initial blank line
    endif
  endif
endfunction

" Delete the current buffer if it is a scratch buffer (any changes are lost).
function! CloseScratch()
  if &buftype == "nofile" && &bufhidden == "hide" && !&swapfile
    " this is a scratch buffer
    bdelete
    return 1
  endif
  return 0
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>f :call Gather(input("Search for: "))<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>F :call Gather(@/)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Esc> :call CloseScratch()<CR>
```

Now when using \f of \F for search, buffer is automatically reloading. Check script's [vikia  page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filter_buffer_on_a_search_result) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. This would be very useful for unix based systems, but how about in windows.